# How to make ant to print full path

Tags: java, android, vim, ant, editor

I am using ant to compile android project. But when compile error happens, it always only prints the file name instead of path + file name. 
Something like this:

```
compile:
    [javac] /home/ccheng/program/predecate_android_sdk/tools/ant/main_rules.xml:384: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 2 source files to /home/ccheng/workspace_helio/android_test/bin/classes
    [javac] MainActivity.java:25: not a statement
    [javac]         asdfasdf
    [javac]         ^
    [javac] MainActivity.java:25: ';' expected
    [javac]         asdfasdf
    [javac]                 ^
    [javac] 2 errors
```

So because of it, however hard i try to configure my vim, the file name always can't be matched.I doubt there must be a method to make ant print the full path or configure vim to match the file name.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem. It's not about the ant, it is caused by `javac`. My previous jdk is `openjdk-1.6-jdk`, it won't print path. As soon as i change to gcj-4.6, then path will be printed. It seems tha openjdk-1.7 also fixes this problem.